# Selenium.click() is not working, instead it is calling an unwanted function

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium to interact with a website. I'm using twitter as an example.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

r = 0

def loadPage():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.set_window_size(800, 800)
    #url = "about:blank"
    url = "http://www.twitter.com/login"
    driver.get(url)
    login(driver)
def login(driver):
    print("login was called")
    name = "session[username_or_email]"
    global r
    try:
        elem = driver.find_element_by_name(name)
        elem.clear()
        elem.send_keys("@someaccount")
        elem.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        actions.send_keys('password')
        actions.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        actions.perform()
        r=0
        retweet(driver)
    except:
        driver.implicitly_wait(3)
        r+=1
        if r <= 5: #only try this 5 times
            print(r)
            login(driver)
        else:
            print("Could not find element " + name)

    #driver.close()
def retweet(driver):
    g = 'g'
    print(driver.current_url)
    icon = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name(g)
    icon.click()

loadPage()
```

When the function retweet() is called, icon.click() at line 43 calls the function login(). (The intended behavior is to perform a click, not to call the function login().)

using "icon.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)" at line 43 exhibits the same behavior.

program outputs:

```
login was called
1
login was called
https://twitter.com/login
1
login was called
https://twitter.com/login
1
login was called
2
login was called
3
login was called
4
login was called
5
login was called
Could not find element session[username_or_email]
```

Comment: Put down the html of the tag you are trying to grab.

Comment: Also use a wait for the element of driver.find_element_by_name(name) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your login function is called again and again, because it found `NoSuchElementException` at line `icon = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name(g)`. Once exception occurred it is going to execute code under except block. Which is nothing but to call login method as per above code.

**Now,** why `NoSuchElementException` occurred even if there are plethora of tag  is available on page ? To answer that if you see your page in inspection mode all `<g>` tags are inside `<svg>` tag. To identify `<svg>` tag we need to use name method of xpath. So if you will use below it will not throw exception:

```
def retweet(driver):
    xpathLink = "//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g']"
    print(driver.current_url)
    icon = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathLink )
    icon.click()
```

**But, still** you will not be clicking retweet link as above xpath will find any link icon present on the twitter page. So if you want to click re-tweet link only you need to use below xpath.

```
xpathRetweet = //div[@data-testid='retweet']//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g']
```

**Note :** Above will always click first re-tweet link on the page. if you want to click all on page. You need to use find_elements o get list of all re-tweet links and click them one by one.